# making list, searching sth and comparing numbers in prolog

Tags: prolog

I could not solve this  challenging problem:

```
name(jack, math, 50).
name(daniel, math, 60).
name(jane, phys, 70).
name(eto, comp, 73).
```

predicate : `nameGrade(P, L, S).` `P` is the list of people who are taking lesson `L` and whose grade is greater than `S`.

`nameGrade([jack], math, 45).` returns true

`nameGrade([jack, daniel], math, 55).` returns false. (because jack scored 50 which is less than 55)

`nameGrade([], phys, 80).` returns true

`nameGrade(X, math, 70).` returns X=[jack, daniel]

`nameGrade([jack, daniel], math, X).` returns X=50. (the less one).

Thank you.

Comment: you already accepted an answer; there is no need to edit your question and replace it with the phrase "My question has been answered".  You should leave your question intact for others to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `findall/3` to return a list of elements satisfying a predicate:

```
nameGrade(P, L, S) :- is_list(P), name(_, _, S), findall(X, (name(X, L, S0), S0 >= S), P).
nameGrade(P, L, S) :- number(S), findall(X, (name(X, L, S0), S0 >= S), P).
```

However, there are some contradictory goals in your requirement. For example, `nameGrade([jack], math, 45)` should fail because both `jack` and `daniel` take `math` and have higher scores than `45`. `nameGrade(X, math, 70)` should return `[]` because no one takes `math` with a higher score than `70`.

Comment: Yes u rigth there is a mistake on name

Comment: Yes u rigth there is a mistake on nameGrade(X, math, 70) actually instead of 70 it can be 20. So it returns [jack, daniel] :) but i think jack, math, 45 is right because jack's grade is over 45.

Comment: It could be but that is non-exhausted searching, the predicate does not try to find ALL combinations satisfying a condition. The predicate would be more meaningful if nameGrade([jack], math, 45) fails but nameGrade([jack, daniel], math, 45) succeeds.